# Insert data into oracle database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am currently working on a registration page where it asks for email, password, password hint, fullname, and identitycardnumber. I have 3 table;

Here are my table structure;

> **HR_APPLICANT**
>  • APPLICANT_PK (NUMBER)
>  • IDENTITYCARD_NUMBER (VARCHAR2(14 BYTE))
>  • EMAIL (VARCHAR2(100 BYTE))
>
> **HR_USERID**
>  • USERID_PK (NUMBER)
>  • APPLICANT_FK (NUMBER)
>  • PASSWORD (VARCHAR2(100 BYTE))
>
> **HR_INFO**
>  • INFO_PK (NUMBER)
>  • APPLICANT_FK (NUMBER)
>  • FULLNAME (VARCHAR2(100 BYTE))

I manage to insert data into table **HR_APPLICANT**. I want to retrieve *APPLICANT_PK* and insert it into the other two tables as *APPLICANT_FK* along with other info however the data is not inserted and there is no error displayed so I don't know which part is wrong.

Here is my code;

```
        string email = txtEmail.Text;
        string password = txtPass1.Text;

        string fullname = txtFullname.Text;
        string identitycard = txtIdentityCard.Text;

        //Insert email and identity card into table HR_APPLICANT
        string insertApplicant = "INSERT INTO HR_APPLICANT(IDENTITYCARD_NUMBER, EMAIL, DATE_CREATE)" +
                                 "VALUES (:identitycard, :email, SYSDATE)";

        oraCon.Open();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insertApplicant, oraCon);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("identitycard", identitycard));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("email", email));
        cmd.ExecuteOracleScalar();

        //Get APPLICANT_PK
        string getApplicantPK = "SELECT APPLICANT_PK FROM HR_APPLICANT" +
                                "WHERE IDENTITYCARD_NUMBER= :identitycard" +
                                "AND EMAIL = :email";

        OracleCommand cmdGetApplicantPK = new OracleCommand(getApplicantPK , oraCon);
        cmdGetApplicantPK .Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("identitycard", identitycard));
        cmdGetApplicantPK .Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("email", email));
        OracleDataReader dr_GetApplicantPK = cmdGetApplicantPK .ExecuteReader();

        if (dr_GetApplicantPK.HasRows)
        {
            dr_GetApplicantPK.Read();

            string applicantFK = dr_GetApplicantPK["APPLICANT_PK"].ToString();
            //Insert applicant_fk and password into table HR_USERID
            string insertUserID = "INSERT INTO HR_USERID (APPLICANT_FK, PASSWORD, DATE_CREATE)" +
                                  "VALUES (:applicantFK, :password, SYSDATE)";

            OracleCommand cmdInsertUserID = new OracleCommand(insertUserID, oraCon);
            cmdInsertUserID.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("applicantFK", applicantFK));
            cmdInsertUserID.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("password", password));
            cmdInsertUserID.ExecuteOracleScalar();

            //Insert name into table HR_INFO
            string insertInfo = "INSERT INTO HR_INFO(APPLICANT_FK, FULLNAME, DATE_CREATE)" +
                                "VALUES (:applicantFK, :fullname, SYSDATE)";

            oraCon.Open();
            OracleCommand cmdInsertInfo = new OracleCommand(insertInfo, oraCon);
            cmdInsertInfo .Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("applicantFK", applicantFK));
            cmdInsertInfo .Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("fullname", fullname));
            cmdInsertInfo .ExecuteOracleScalar();
            }

            dr_GetApplicantPK.Close();
            oraCon.Close();
```

Comment: How does APPLICANT_PK get its value?

Comment: @Littlefoot APPLICANT_PK is auto-generated as it is set to not null

Comment: The fact that it is set to NOT NULL doesn't mean that it is auto-generated; it just means that table won't accept NULL values in that column. Which database version do you use? Is it an identity column (so yes, it is auto-generated)? If not, once again: how does it get its value?

Comment: I have no problem with APPLICANT_PK as if I insert data there will be values there. I'm using oracle and even if I manually insert the data from SQL developer, the primary key will be auto-generated. 

I have no problem with inserting data into table HR_APPLICANT. My problem is now to retrieve the APPLICANT_PK from HR_APPLICANT and insert it into table HR_USERID and HR_INFO as APPLICANT_FK, no data are managed to be inserted and no error displayed.

Comment: OK, then it is auto-generated, doesn't matter how (as identity column or a sequence via database trigger). Good. I don't know asp.net nor C#, but - is there anything like **commit** you could issue? After all INSERT statements run, as of Oracle, they won't be "saved" into the database until commit is performed. Could that be a problem? Because, code you wrote looks OK. Even if you don't fetch APPLICANT_PK and use it as APPLICANT_FK, there are no other conditions which would prevent insert to happen.